# Is there a function for google spreadsheet that lets me convert a keyword to hyperlink representing result of its Google search?

Tags: spreadsheet, google-docs

I have a spreadsheet with many names, I need to perform google search for some of them .

Is there a function that takes a keyword and converts it to a hyperlink representing the google search of the same keyword so that if i click it it will take me to the results directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the concat function.

[Demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnD32p0tx1xbdEZVVGVsRDBJa1lxUjlaaHBuRlBqU1E)

The formula is:

```
=CONCAT("http://google.com/search?q=",A1)
```

You can copy that to the formula bar.

Comment: It is difficult to view the formula in your spreadsheet, can you make it more explicit ?

Comment: I can copy , past the formula ...save it , looks good but for some reason my doc is not recognizing it as a hyperlink...just plain concatenated text

Comment: @user2760, I've put the formula in the answer.

Comment: Thank you..i had used the same one it worked for me after i added the hyperlink formula to it